# Getting 400 Bad Request using Power BI Connector with Aprimo API

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I'm trying to access a custom report designed in the Aprimo SaaS with Power BI.

I'm following the instructions here on Aprimo's website, https://developers.aprimo.com/marketing-operations/using-external-reporting-tools/connecting-powerbi/, but I'm getting a 400 Bad Request response.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Aprimo support and was given the following support.

From Power BI:
1.  Click ‘Edit Queries’
2.  Home > Data Source Settings > Global Permissions
3.  Select problematic connection > Edit Permissions > Edit > Basic > Input Report ID and Token > OK > Close